# FileNotFoundException with MediaPlayer.create() reading from /res/raw

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-resources

I have a tiny uncompress .wav file in my /res/raw directory called keyclick.wav (/res/raw/keyclick.wav).

However, I'm occasionally seeing an exception thrown which causes the activity to crash:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed at ...
android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFdNative(Native Method)
android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFd(AssetManager.java:427)
android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:857)
android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:662)
```

It says "it is probably compressed" but I've double checked, it is not compressed.

This is how I instantiate the MediaPlayer:

```
this.clickPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this.getActivity(), R.raw.keyclick);
```

I uploaded the file so you can see it directly:

http://inadaydevelopment.com/stackoverflow/keyclick.wav

The file is only 664 bytes and it's not compressed. Why is the system failing to get a file descriptor?

Comment: Can you show the code as well?

Comment: @Kenny Wyland.. From the error logs, I guess the `AssetManager` is unable to find the file in it's `AssetPaths` i.e. list of pre-known paths. If `/res/raw` path is not a hard-constraint, can you check if you still face the same issue with `/mnt/sdcard0` as the directory?

Comment: @DigCamara I've added the code that I use to create the MediaPlayer.

Comment: @Ganesh the real problem is that it never happens to me, but I've embedded some error reporting code into one of our apps and so I get these reports from the world-at-large. I can't reproduce the error myself.

Comment: @KennyWyland does your error reporting give any other context information to go off of? i.e. does this always happen on the same piece of hardware? if so which device is it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I didn't want to collect information about the device itself (to avoid scaring users), but perhaps I'll need to update the system to pull some anonymous hardware info so that I can determine if the problem is a particular handset.

Answer (score 1):

Kenny, have you tried playing the file using this approach:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.keyclick);
mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```